# Java.sql.sqlexception: The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans, sqlexception

When I am updating my Date Field  the update does not works from NetBeans and Below exception is raised

**Java.sql.sqlexception: The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value**

However I run the same query the query works fine in SQL Query Analyzer (SQL Server 2000)

I am formatting the Date Value to be updated as follows in NetBeans.

```
        JXDatePicker jDatePicker = (JXDatePicker) comp;
        Date date = jDatePicker.getDate();
        if (date != null) {
        try {
            String expectedPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
            String currentFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS";

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatReq = new SimpleDateFormat(expectedPattern);

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatCurr = new SimpleDateFormat(currentFormat);          

            // To Convert Date To Required Format For DB

            //First Prepare A String In Current Format dd-MM-yyyy
            // Then Convert To The Date In The Current Format dd-MM-yyyy
            // Then Convert Into  String In The Desired Format yyyy-MM-dd
            String strDate =     dateFormatReq.format(dateFormatCurr.parse(dateFormatCurr.format(date)));

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ChangeJControlProperties.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        } 

String query =update myTable
               set date=strDate  where id=myDd
```

**For Date 2013-07-05 it updates successfully.**

**For Date 2013-06-28 it displays the above  exception**

Comment: Do you actually need to format the date twice? I can't shake the thought that there's a redundant/unnecessary parse there. What happens if you simply format the date from the picker with the required format only?

Comment: @Zec But the problem is not with the formatting data twice;

Comment: I'm assuming you tried my suggestion before rejecting it. You take a date value from a control designed for defining date values. At this stage, it's of the type Date. In your parsing/casting/formatting, you first turn it into a string of "Curr" format. Note the date had no format until you imposed one. Then you parse that string back into a date type. This renders the original formatting redundant. Then you format that date back into a string. If the problem does not reside with this redundant formatting, what then is causing your conversion exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved as the Default Language Selected was Thai, when i change it to English the exception does not  come and the problem disappears.

Comment: If I may ask, default language of what?

Comment: Default Language Of Windows